# easy scheme question

Tags: list, scheme

how can I find a list from given database??
Database:

```
(10 math phys)

(11 math chem)

(13 bio chem)

(15 geo phys)
```

I want to implement `time` which shows the first and second exams in a list.

```
>(time ’10)

(list ‘math ‘phys)

>(time ’19)

empty
```

And I want to implement `secondExams` which returns the time of second exams.

```
>(secondExams ‘phys)

(list ‘10 ’15)

>(secondExams ‘chem)

(list ’11 ’13)
```

thank you

Comment: Is this homework? Please tag it as such if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's clarify your database format.  Make it a list of lists:

```
(define database
  '((10 math phys)
    (11 math chem)
    (13 bio chem)
    (15 geo phys)))
```

Then *time* just needs to step through your list recursively, and compare the first element of the sub-list with your target value.  If we find no matching value, we'll return the empty list.  We'll do this in a helper procedure to match the functionality you're precisely seeking.

```
(define time-ish
  (lambda (target lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) lst)
          ((eq? target (caar lst)) (cdar lst))
          (else
           (time-ish target (cdr lst))))))

(define (time lookin-for)
  (time-ish lookin-for database))
```

Then we can do something very similar for secondExams.  Except we'll recursively build a list of matches this time.

```
(define exam-helper
  (lambda (target lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) lst)
          ((eq? target (third (car lst))) (cons (first (car lst))
                                                (exam-helper target (cdr lst))))
          (else
           (exam-helper target (cdr lst))))))

(define (secondExams lookin-for)
  (exam-helper lookin-for database))
```

I haven't tested this code, but I'm pretty sure it'll work for you.

Comment: Since you offered style help on mine, I ask a style-question of you: Why do you use both first and car? What determined which usage? Similarly: Why only cdr but no rest? Can't we forever forget the use of car and cdr to help outsiders join the language without requiring a brief aside to the history of the implementation of lisps?

Comment: No reason to prefer car vs first.  Just using different ones to make sure the question-asker sees what tools they have available to dig though lists.  I didn't use 'rest' as I'm not familiar with it.  I don't see it after doing some quick searching in the R5RS spec.

Comment: first/rest are the semantically rich aliases of car/cdr. Also, I tried to delete my answer, as it is inferior to / subset of yours. Apparently it is only a "vote" to delete. A pity. It may have been helpful to the poster had you not come along. Now it could only add confusion.